# pdf: are CID Type 0C fonts better than Type 1 fonts?

Tags: fonts, pdf

For years, I took care to only have Type 1 fonts in the PDF produced by LaTeX.

Now switching to LuaLaTex, I realize that LuaLaTex uses by default "CID Type 0C".

Example output of `pdffonts`:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
JPVZSN+LMRoman17-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     36  0
```

Compared to Type 1 fonts, the encoding is different, and the unicode flag also (`uni` above, `=yes` for CID Type 0C).

Are CID Type 0C fonts better than T1 fonts? Why?

Comment: The depends on what you mean better. They have a wider platform support but is that better?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22549 and the related questions https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132173 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200880

Comment: @Thérèse: Thanks, but I believe a comprehensive answer should be *here*, as this site is IMNSHO better suited for questions about font technology.